# KKT optimality conditions for Max and Min under different constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

I've found many papers and seen several posts on here that use notations for the KKT conditions different from the book I am using, [this book.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470462728) The book uses the following:

Given the following,
$$\begin{align*}
\text{Minimize}\:&\textbf{cx}\\
\text{subject to}\:&\textbf{Ax}\geq \textbf{b}\\
&\textbf{x}\geq \textbf{0}\\
\end{align*}
$$
The the authors state that the KKT conditions are
$$
\begin{align*}
&\textbf{Ax}\geq\textbf{b}\:,\:\textbf{x}\geq\textbf{0}\\
&\textbf{wA}+\textbf{v}=\textbf{c}\:,\:\textbf{w,v}\geq\textbf{0}\\
&\textbf{w}(\textbf{Ax}-\textbf{b})=0\:,\:\textbf{vx}=0
\end{align*}
$$
where the first, second, and third are called primal feasibility, dual feasibility, and complementary slackness, respectively. I got somewhat lost during the derivation of this. Also, suppose we change the given system to the following ones:
$$\begin{align*}
\text{Minimize}\:&\textbf{cx}\\
\text{subject to}\:&\textbf{Ax}\leq \textbf{b}\\
&\textbf{x}\geq \textbf{0}\\
\end{align*}
$$
$$\begin{align*}
\text{Maximize}\:&\textbf{cx}\\
\text{subject to}\:&\textbf{Ax}\geq \textbf{b}\\
&\textbf{x}\geq \textbf{0}\\
\end{align*}
$$
$$\begin{align*}
\text{Maximize}\:&\textbf{cx}\\
\text{subject to}\:&\textbf{Ax}\leq \textbf{b}\\
&\textbf{x}\geq \textbf{0}\\
\end{align*}
$$
$$\begin{align*}
\text{Minimize}\:&\textbf{cx}\\
\text{subject to}\:&\textbf{A}_1\textbf{x}=\textbf{b}_1\\
&\textbf{A}_2\textbf{x}\geq \textbf{b}_2\\
&\textbf{x}\geq \textbf{0}\\
\end{align*}
$$
How would I modify the KKT conditions for these new systems?

Comment: did you appreciate my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important step is forming the Lagrangian. Let me give two examples

**Example 1**
$$\begin{align*}
\text{Minimize}\:&\textbf{cx}\\
\text{subject to}\:&\textbf{Ax}\leq \textbf{b}\\
&\textbf{x}\geq \textbf{0}\\
\end{align*}
$$
The Lagrangian is $L(x,\lambda) = c^Tx + w^T(Ax-b) + v^T(-x)$ with $w \geq 0$. The $+$ since it is minimization ($-$ for maximization), and the parts between parentheses are (always) the $\leq$ sides.

**Example 2**
$$\begin{align*}
\text{Minimize}\:&\textbf{cx}\\
\text{subject to}\:&\textbf{A}_1\textbf{x}=\textbf{b}_1\\
&\textbf{A}_2\textbf{x}\geq \textbf{b}_2\\
&\textbf{x}\geq \textbf{0}\\
\end{align*}
$$
The Lagrangian is $L(x,\lambda) = c^Tx + v^T(A_1x-b_1) + w^T(b_2-A_2x)-y^Tx$ with $w\geq0$. Here $v$ does not have to be nonnegative. You would arrive at the same function if you rewrite the equality as two inequalities.

**Next step**

After forming the Lagrangian you take the derivative with respect to $x$ to get the dual feasibility conditions. The other conditions follow trivially.

Comment: Thanks. Quick question, in the example I gave, how did the authors get the dual feasibility? The $\textbf{wA}$ makes sense but I don't know where the other variables came from.

Comment: @TomásPalamás $v$ comes from the nonnegativity constraint. In my initial answer you would get $c + A^T w \geq 0$, with my updated answer you get $c+A^T w - v = 0$ with $v \geq 0$